# How to get GUI control's property value from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, reflection, backgroundworker

VS2005 / Framework 2.0 / VB.NET

I'm using a BackgroundWorker control to do some long time work which updates a modal progress form (.ShowDialog()).

I've managed to **SET** main form properties values from BW DoWork / ProgressChanged events and even invoke form's methods (with a little help from Reflection objects http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-using-reflection-to-get-object-information).

the only thing I don't know how to do is to **GET** main form's control's properties back to the BW thread.

Comment: Can you show some code? Reflection might not be the right solution for the job, you might need just a InvokeRequired check.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all Set methods in the Reflection API have a corresponding Get method, so the code from the example could be:

```
MyObject myObjectInstance = new MyObject();
System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fieldInfo = myObjectType.GetFields();
string strValue = string.Empty;
int intValue = 0;
object objValue = null;

foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo info in fieldInfo)
{
   switch (info.Name)
   {
      case "myStringField":
         strValue = (string)info.GetValue(myObjectInstance);
        break;
      case "myIntField":
        intValue = (int)info.GetValue(myObjectInstance);
        break;
     case "myObjectField":
        objValue = info.GetValue(myObjectInstance);
        break;
}
```

However, this is a inefficient way to get/set a single value if you have lots of properties, so you can use the GetField method, like this:

```
myType = myObjectInstance.GetType();
strValue = (string)myType.GetField("myStringField").GetValue(myObjectInstance);
intValue = (int)myType.GetField("myIntField").GetValue(myObjectInstance);
objValue = myType.GetField("myObjectField").GetValue(myObjectInstance);
```

And one more thing, Reflection is a great tool, but there's a price to pay. Your code is less maintainable (after all, you are using string for the field names) and the performance is severely hurt. My bottom line is to try avoiding reflection whenever possible, so please try to look for an alternate solution first.

Comment: Is the GetField method thread safe? because the real problem is to pass the returned value back to the BackgroundWorker thread?

Comment: Using reflection is not safer that using the equivalent object, so if you have race conditions without reflection, they wont dissapear because of it. Please show some code, as I think that you do not need reflection at all to achieve the scenario you described.